# JRuby to jar executable

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I've been learning Ruby and if I understand correctly, I can get my Ruby scripts, and use JRuby to create Java class files, essentially allowing my Ruby scripts to be run in the JVM.  I have successfully managed to create a .class file from my Ruby script.

I would like to know, is it possible to make this class file into an executable file?  Am I supposed to use Warble or Rawr to do this?  I installed the Warble GEM but I couldn't work out how to use it and I'm not sure if it's even what I need...  What's the easiest way?

Comment: Just use a normal `jar` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type this in the command line:

```
cd C:/Users/Someone/Path/To/Class/
jar cvfm executable.jar manifest.mf Foo.class
```

Where `manifest.mf` is something like

> Main-Class: Foo

Change C:/Users/Someone/Path/To/Class/ to the path to your files and change `Foo` to the name of your class. This will create a jar file called "executable.jar."

Comment: Okay so I did what you wrote; I ran `jar cvfm executable.jar manifest.mf HelloWorld.class`.  That created a file called `executable.jar`.  I then attempted to run my jar file using the command `java -jar executable.jar` but that didn't work: `no main manifest attribute, in executable.jar`.

I don't know why it would say this because I created a `manifest.mf` and put the line `Main-Class: HelloWorld` in it.  Am I supposed to put something else?

Comment: @user968243 try putting two blank lines, like `Main-Class: HelloWorld(enter)(enter)`. Also, make sure your `.class` and `.mf` are in the same directory. Also make sure that your manifest is called "manifest.mf" and not "manifest.mf.txt."

Comment: Okay, the enter enter thing works (seems a bit silly, but hey, if it works)!  Anyway, I have another error now, when I go to run it, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and that's fulled by a whole heap of lines beginning with `at java...`.  Advice appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @user968243 If you are running it from the command prompt, you have to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334148/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror . It should work fine when double-clicking it.