# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I created the program using Net Beans in Windows, it works fine. When I transferred the code alone to HP-UX, I'm encountering below error.

Sorry for my question, I am new to java.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaapplication2/JavaApplication2
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javaapplication2.JavaApplication2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
Could not find the main class: javaapplication2.JavaApplication2. Program will exit.
```

compiling the code gave me two classes:

```
JavaApplication2$1.class
JavaApplication2.class
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: javaapplication2.JavaApplication2
```

I also executed jar command inside the main directory where classes, manifest.mf and code are located.

```
/opt/java6/bin/jar -cvfm app.jar MANIFEST.MF *class
```

I'm wondering what may be the cause of the error encountered.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class JavaApplication2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @return 
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here


  File directory = new File("/idmp/MJMN/ICMS_to_ZERORATED/src");
  //list only files
  File files[] = directory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
      @Override
      public boolean accept (File pathname) {
          String name = pathname.getName();
          return name.startsWith("S") && pathname.isFile();
      }
  }

  );


  //read files line by line
  for (File d : files) {


       FileReader fr;
        fr = new FileReader(d);
       BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
       String line;
       String file_name = d.getName();           

       PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("/idmp/MJMN/ICMS_to_ZERORATED/dst/" + file_name);
       PrintStream orig = System.out;
       System.setOut(ps);


       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            String RCDTYP = line.substring(0,2);
                int RCDTYP_int = Integer.parseInt(RCDTYP);
           if (RCDTYP_int  == 50 ){ //read line with '50
               //System.out.println(line);
               //String CALLING_NUMBER = "";
               //String CALLED_NUMBER = "";

             //GET BILLABLE_CALL_DUR_MIN
               String tmp_emrtyp = line.substring(175,180);
               String emrtyp = tmp_emrtyp.replaceAll("\\s+","");
                    int emrtyp_int = Integer.parseInt(emrtyp);
               String emrtmm = line.substring(127,138);
               String emrtss = line.substring(138,141);

               String emrtmm_no_zero = emrtmm.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
                    int emrtmm_int = Integer.parseInt(emrtmm_no_zero);
               String emrtss_no_zero = emrtss.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
                    int emrtss_int = Integer.parseInt(emrtss_no_zero);

               int BCDM;

               if (emrtyp_int == 1001){
                    BCDM = 1;                     
               } else {
                    BCDM = emrtmm_int + emrtss_int;
               }

               //String tmp_BCDM = Integer.toString(BCDM);                                                       
                String Space_20 = String.format("%20s", "");
                String Space_29 = String.format("%29s", "");
                String Space_9 = String.format("%9s", "");
                String Space_5 = String.format("%5s", "");
                String Space_2 = String.format("%2s", "");
                String Space_1 = String.format("%1s", "");
                String Space_8 = String.format("%8s", "");
                String Space_7 = String.format("%7s", "");
               //Leading zeros
                String str_BCDM = String.format("%011d",BCDM);

                String CALLING_NUMBER          =line.substring(2,22);
                String CALLED_NUMBER           =line.substring(32,52);
                String CALL_DATETIME           =line.substring(92,107);
                String SERVICE_NUMBER          =Space_20;
                String CUSTOMER_NUMBER         =Space_9;
                String RATE_PLAN_CODE          =Space_5;
                String BILLABLE_CALL_DUR_MIN   =str_BCDM;
                String BILLABLE_CALL_DUR_SEC   ="000";
                String ACTUAL_CALL_DUR_MIN     =emrtmm;
                String ACTUAL_CALL_DUR_SEC     =emrtss;
                String RATED_AMT               ="000000000000000";
                String JURISDICTION_CODE       =Space_2;
                String CALL_TYPE               =tmp_emrtyp;
                String PEAK_OFFPEAK_INDICATOR  =Space_1;
                String BILLING_CYCLE           ="00";
                String SERVICE_CODE            =line.substring(57,59);
                String UNIT_OF_MEASURE         ="MIN  ";
                String CURRENCY_CODE           ="PHP";
                String FROM_CELL               =Space_5;
                String TO_CELL                 =Space_5;
                String FROM_PLACE              =Space_5 + Space_5;
                String TO_PLACE                =Space_5 + Space_5;
                String BILLDATE                =Space_8;
                String BASESTATION             =Space_5 + Space_5;
                String DATE_LAST_UPDATE        ="000000000";
                String TIME_LAST_UPDATE        ="0000000";
                String USAGE_TYPE_GLCODE       =Space_7;
                String TOLLFILE                =Space_8;
                String Filler                  =Space_29 + "|";

               System.out.println(CALLING_NUMBER          + 
                                  CALLED_NUMBER           +
                                  CALL_DATETIME           +
                                  SERVICE_NUMBER          +
                                  CUSTOMER_NUMBER         +
                                  RATE_PLAN_CODE          +
                                  BILLABLE_CALL_DUR_MIN   +
                                  BILLABLE_CALL_DUR_SEC   +
                                  ACTUAL_CALL_DUR_MIN     +
                                  ACTUAL_CALL_DUR_SEC     +
                                  RATED_AMT               +
                                  JURISDICTION_CODE       +
                                  CALL_TYPE               +
                                  PEAK_OFFPEAK_INDICATOR  +
                                  BILLING_CYCLE           +
                                  SERVICE_CODE            +
                                  UNIT_OF_MEASURE         +
                                  CURRENCY_CODE           +
                                  FROM_CELL               +
                                  TO_CELL                 +
                                  FROM_PLACE              +
                                  TO_PLACE                +
                                  BILLDATE                +
                                  BASESTATION             +
                                  DATE_LAST_UPDATE        +
                                  TIME_LAST_UPDATE        +
                                  USAGE_TYPE_GLCODE       +
                                  TOLLFILE                +
                                  Filler                  
                                    ); 


          //closing 'if'
           } 

           //String emr = line.substring(0,2);

           //System.out.println(emr);

       } br.close();
       fr.close();
       System.setOut(orig);
       ps.close();


}

    /**read file **/

   /** try {

        FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(args[10]);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fStream));
     while (in.ready()) {
          System.out.println (in.readLine());

       }
      in.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File input error");
    } **/



}

    }
```

Comment: did you only transfer the code? it's the .class file you (should) run, not the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exception in thread 'main' java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334148/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Comment: @Stultuske I compiled the code and zipped it with manifest.mf and classes

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the error by simply removing the package name.